# what will cause socket write throws connection timeout exception

Tags: java, sockets

What will cause a `write()` method throws Connection timeout exception?

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out

    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:116)
```

Comment: Can we see all the relevant code and all the stack trace?  What stream writer are you using?

Comment: we use apache http core's defaultbhttpclientconnection.sendrequestenttiy to send request body,[code here]( https://github.com/apache/httpcore/blob/4.4.x/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java#L156)

Comment: Connection Timeout usually means that the server isn't responding, or responding in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

Connection died (on the way or opposite side of the channel), because for example no communication did not occur for a long time. This can be resolved (if you need to) by applying [keepAlives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive(boolean)) on the socket.

In huge majority of cases - from what I have seen - this is *normal behavior* exception, because the network partitions do happen from time (this would be a problem if the communication is only in your data center and the exception is common). But if its related to server-client (browser) communication, there should be nothing to worry about.